# Can I call libxml parser from multiple asynchronous network calls?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a piece of code that uses NSURLConnection to fetch a network resource asynchronously and parse some XML as it streams in. The XML parsing is handled by libxml2 which is available as a framework in the iOS SDK. This works perfectly when I invoke it once, parse the XML and release the resources by calling xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt).

My problem is that when I run this same code in multiple threads, all of a sudden i see EXC_BAD_ACCESS pop up which I trace back to the libxml2. Specifically the xmlParserCtxtPtr context which is initialized and used for XML parsing seems to throw the EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I release it after I am done retrieving the resource. 
The exception goes away if I do not release this context i.e. call xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt).

This leads me to believe that my issues are some how related to libxml framework available in iOS not being thread safe.

Sure enough, I see this when I google the issue: 
From: http://xmlsoft.org/threads.html

> Starting with 2.4.7, libxml2 makes provisions to ensure that concurrent threads can safely work in parallel parsing different documents. There is however a couple of things to do to ensure it:

```
* configure the library accordingly using the --with-threads options
* call xmlInitParser() in the "main" thread before using any of the libxml2 API (except possibly selecting a different memory allocator)
```

So I have two questions:
1.) Is my assumption correct that the version of libxml that I am using is not thread safe and hence causing the issue? Has anyone else seen this?
2.) I know that the iOS bundles libxml2.2.x - would it work if I get libxml2.4.7 and add it to my project? Would that cause any rejections on the app store?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using   xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt) to "release" the push parser? The libxml structs are not objects so they will not respond to messages.

Comment: Yes - I am using the xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt)  to 'release' the parser. Let me clarify that in my post as well.

Comment: Are you using the same parser context across multiple threads? XML data has to be processed serially. One parser per URL request. Hard to tell without seeing your actual code.

Comment: Each thread has its own parser context. The parser context is wrapped in an object that does the async network call - where it is initialized right before connecting to the URL and freed up once the connection is complete. Multiple instances of this object are fired off to fetch the XML - which is where I see this problem.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is hard to tell if the source of the error is in your wrapper object or the lib. Worth submitting a bug report of you feel that the issue is in the lib shipped with iOS.

Comment: Turns out it was sheer stupidity on my part. I had a static data structure that was shared across all network calls - obviously that would work fine for single calls but not for multi-threaded calls.